# Bootstrap 4 Fixed Bottom Nav with dropup. How?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

*I have researched the site for this solution prior to posting. None seem to work with this approach.*

**I have created the following template in** [Pingendo.](http://www.pingendo.com)

```css
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand text-warning p-0 py-1" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> <a class="navbar-text p-0 text-muted" href="0.html">HOME</a>
      <nav class="nav"><a class="nav-link p-0 py-1 text-warning" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i></a></nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
  <!-- START MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container py-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <!-- START FORM - CUSTOM !-->
          <form action="" class="text-center mb-2" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Client, address, phone..." type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm border border-warning" type="button"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</span></span>
              </span>
              </span>
              </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- END FORM - CUSTOM !-->
          <p class="p-0 m-0 mb-1 form-control-sm text-center">(n) search results</p>
          <!-- START LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
          <div class="list-group">
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
          </div>
          <!-- END LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
  <!-- START NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container"><a class="nav-brand p-0 text-muted" href="#client"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o fa-lg mr-2"></i>Last, First</a>
      <!-- Default dropup button -->
      <div class="btn-group dropup">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Dropup</button>
        <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="nav"><a class="nav-link p-1 pl-3 text-warning" href="#view_project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-lg"></i></a> <a class="nav-link p-1 pl-3" href="#switch_project"><span class="badge badge-dark nav-item border border-warning text-warning">00:24</span></a>        <a class="nav-link p-1 pl-1" href="#switch_project_task"><span class="badge border border-warning badge-warning">&nbsp;PU&nbsp;</span></a></nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**It follows this basic layout structure:**

navbar fixed-top

container

navbar fixed-bottom

**I then visited the Bootstrap 4 page about a** [Dropup variation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation) **of the Dropdown menu.**

I add the following sample code to my NAVBAR BOTTOM like so:

```
<!-- Default dropup button -->
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Dropup</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that it is not working like it works on their website.

**It continues to pop down..** Perhaps someone could point out something I've missed?

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dropdown inside a navbar is supported by `Popper.js` used by Bootstrap to align the dropdown.
>    https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

[image: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment]

So as an alternative add this to your css. It should work.

```
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}
```

Full example

```css
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- !-->
  <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand text-warning p-0 py-1" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> <a class="navbar-text p-0 text-muted" href="0.html">HOME</a>
      <nav class="nav"><a class="nav-link p-0 py-1 text-warning" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i></a></nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
  <!-- START MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container py-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <!-- START FORM - CUSTOM !-->
          <form action="" class="text-center mb-2" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Client, address, phone..." type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm border border-warning" type="button"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="input-group-btn">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</span></span>
              </span>
              </span>
              </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- END FORM - CUSTOM !-->
          <p class="p-0 m-0 mb-1 form-control-sm text-center">(n) search results</p>
          <!-- START LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
          <div class="list-group">
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p>
                <small>3 days ago</small></div>
              <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
              <br>
              <small><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> &nbsp;801-555-1234</small></a>
            <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
          </div>
          <!-- END LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
  <!-- START NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container"><a class="nav-brand p-0 text-muted" href="#client"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o fa-lg mr-2"></i>Last, First</a>
      <!-- Default dropup button -->
      <div class="btn-group dropup">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Dropup</button>
        <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="nav"><a class="nav-link p-1 pl-3 text-warning" href="#view_project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-lg"></i></a> <a class="nav-link p-1 pl-3" href="#switch_project"><span class="badge badge-dark nav-item border border-warning text-warning">00:24</span></a>        <a class="nav-link p-1 pl-1" href="#switch_project_task"><span class="badge border border-warning badge-warning">&nbsp;PU&nbsp;</span></a></nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very nice. I just had one quick question regarding to right-alignment of the dropdown-menu. Check this out - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment 
This seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are using alpha version of the bootstrap. follow this documentation - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Comment: I got it! added CSS left: -100%; 
It works but it this valid?

Comment: After some testing it seems dropdown inside footer nav is not working as it supposed to be. I'll be raising an issue with bootstrap github. And yes `left: -100%;` is a valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add class **dropup** to your *class="btn-group btn-group-lg"* or your button wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Version for Future Reference**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.1.css" type="text/css">
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .dropup .dropdown-menu {
            top: auto;
            bottom: 100%;
            left: -100%;
            margin-bottom: .125rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- !-->
    <!-- !-->
    <!-- !-->
    <!-- !-->
    <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container p-0">
            <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - NAV LEFT - CUSTOM !-->
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="/main"> <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i> </a>
            </nav>
            <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - NAV LEFT - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - NAV CENTER - CUSTOM !-->
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav-link px-0 text-muted" href="#blank"> Last, First</a>
            </nav>
            <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - NAV CENTER - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- START NAVBAR TOP - NAV RIGHT - CUSTOM !-->
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pl-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x text-warning"></i> </a>
            </nav>
            <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - NAV RIGHT - CUSTOM !-->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR TOP - CUSTOM !-->
    <!-- START MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
    <div class="py-5">
        <div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <!-- START FORM - CUSTOM !-->
                    <form action="" class="text-center mb-2" method="post">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Client, address, phone..." type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-warning border border-warning" type="button">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</button>
      </span> </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- END FORM - CUSTOM !-->
                    <p class="p-0 m-0 mb-1 form-control-sm text-center">(n) search results</p>
                    <!-- START LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p> <small>3 days ago</small> </div> <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
                            <br> <small>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
        &nbsp;801-555-1234
    </small> </a>
                        <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                        <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p> <small>3 days ago</small> </div> <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
                            <br> <small>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
        &nbsp;801-555-1234
    </small> </a>
                        <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                        <!-- START LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action form-control-sm flex-column align-items-start mb-1" href="#">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <p class="mb-0">TESLA, NIKOLA</p> <small>3 days ago</small> </div> <small>123 Main Street, Salt Lake City, UT 84101</small>
                            <br> <small>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
        &nbsp;801-555-1234
    </small> </a>
                        <!-- END LIST-GROUP-ITEM - CUSTOM !-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- END LIST-GROUP SEARCH RESULTS - CUSTOM !-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN SECTION - CUSTOM !-->
    <!-- START NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container p-0">
            <!-- START NAVBAR BOTTOM - NAV LEFT - CUSTOM !-->
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-lg"></i> </a>
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-lg"></i> </a>
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-superscript fa-lg"></i> </a>
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half fa-lg"></i> </a>
                <a class="nav-link text-warning px-0 pr-4" href="#blank"> <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-lg"></i> </a>
            </nav>
            <!-- END NAVBAR BOTTOM - NAV LEFT - CUSTOM !-->
            <!-- Default dropup button -->
            <div class="btn-group dropup btn-group-sm">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-warning" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown">CLOCK IN <span class="sr-only">&nbsp;</span> </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu text-right">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR BOTTOM - CUSTOM !-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```